# Hot redeployment not working on Wildfly 10.1.Final

Tags: deployment, jboss, wildfly, wildfly-10

I have a multi-maven war project that I'm trying to deploy in Wildfly. I'm using the JBoss Tools plugin in eclipse to do the deployment (incremental, full publish) and I can see the files being deployed, updated in wildfly's deployment directory. My problem is the xhtml file rendered in the browser is not updated. What I tried:

1.) clear the browser's cache - no effect
2.) open a private browser window - no effect
3.) added a no-cache filter in wildfly

```
<server name="default-server">
    <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
        <filter-ref name="cache-control" predicate="path-suffix['.html'] or path-suffix['.jsf'] or path-suffix['.xhtml'] or path-suffix['.css'] or path-suffix['.js']"/>
    </host>
</server>
<filters>
    <response-header name="cache-control" header-name="Cache-Control" header-value="no-cache"/>
</filters>
```

Seems like Wildfly has some deep caching, because when you run incremental publish and then restart the server the changes are reflected.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was solved by adding param: javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD in web.xml.

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
    <param-value>2</param-value> <!-- Should be -1 for production. -->
</context-param>
```

Answer (score 0):

For standalone:

When already connected to CLI:

```
deploy /path/to/application.war
```

Connecting and deploying in a single command:

```
jboss-cli.sh --connect command="deploy /path/to/application.war"
```

Connecting, deploying, and authenticating in a single command:

```
jboss-cli.sh --connect --user=admin --password=redhat command="deploy /path/to/application.war"
```

For domain:

Deploying to all groups:

```
deploy /path/to/application.war --all-server-groups
```

Deploying only to specified groups:

```
deploy /path/to/application.war --server-groups=server_group_1,server_group_2
```

These domain commands can also be used like above to connect and/or authenticate in a single command.

User can not deploy application to specific server/servers in domain mode.
The application.war should be an archived application (not an exploded war).

Comment: Hi, thank for the reply but you are talking about deployment. I can do that using eclipse's jboss tools. My problem is re-deployment. When I changed a file in wildfly's deployment folder it doesn't get reflected in the web browser.

Comment: If you are updating web pages then enabling development mode should help if made any changes in web page. To enable development mode add below parameters in jsp-config tag:   <jsp-config check-interval="10" development="true"/>

Comment: Hi, I'm currently using jsf so I'm not sure where to put that.